# Can we apply only the annihilation operator on Strawberry Fields?

Tags: optical-quantum-computing

[Strawberry Fields](https://strawberryfields.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) allows us to access photonic hardware for continuous variable quantum computing.

I was wondering if we can implement just the $\hat{a}$ (annihilation operator) on coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$.

I am skeptical because the annihilation operator is a non-hermitian operator, and it will lead to a non-unitary transformation. However, these platforms only allow unitary transformations.

Am I correct in assuming this?